# Calling Function in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL `function FN_CALC(emp_sal)` which returns a Value.
PL/SQL Function is working properly.
Using the return value of the function I need to update the my oracle query(ie when function returns 1000 one condition else another condition).

Based on the output of Function I need to update the query.
Below is my query.

```
update EMPLOYEE_MASTER 
set EMP_GRADE = case 
    when EMP_GRADE < (FN_CALC(emp_sal)) 
    then EMP_GRADE ='A'
    end;
```

Kindly help to solve.That is depending on the output of PL/SQL Function the udpate statement should work.

Regards
Prakash

Comment: You can call a function from sql query as follows : select function_name(param) from dual; You may execute the update statement I've posted as the answer and accept & up vote it if that works fine, otherwise, post the result/error so that its clear to suggest next steps

Comment: upvote pls, being greedy for reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE employee_master 
    SET emp_grade = (
    CASE 
        WHEN (emp_grade < (SELECT FN_CALC(emp_sal) FROM DUAL))
        THEN 'A'
        ELSE emp_grade
    END);
```